Problem with beamer overlays and minipages
The following code should (I think) generate a slide that has two columns and two overlays. The first overlay should have AAA in the left column and a blue square in the right. The second overlay should have AAA followed by BBB on the left, and a red square on the right. The blue square doesn't appear, but I cannot see why. If the left minipage is deleted, the squares appear as expected. What am I doing wrong here?
[pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024/Cygwin)]
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{0.43\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item AAA
\pause\item BBB
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.4\textheight}
\only<1>{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}}
\only<2->{\textcolor{red}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}


\pause is a very crude command. It basically hides the rest of the frame, including the blue rectangle. Instead you can use overlays for BBB:
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{0.43\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item AAA
\item<2-> BBB
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.4\textheight}
\only<1>{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}}
\only<2->{\textcolor{red}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}



I had read that \pause was crude, but this is the first time I've been adversely affected by it. The actual usage case had graphics (which appeared after \pause) and text (which didn't). Your solution deals with that too. Lesson learned - I'll stop using \pause!

@IanThompson You won't regret saying adieu to pauses :)
